# Terminology for exact symplectomorphism

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, terminology, symplectic-topology

Let $(M,\omega = d\alpha)$ be an exact symplectic manifold. Then a symplectomorphism $\varphi \colon M \to M$ is said to be **exact**, iff $\varphi^*\alpha - \alpha$ is exact. Is there a terminology for the special case when $\varphi^*\alpha = \alpha$? I thought of something like *the symplectomorphism preserves the exact symplectic form*.

Answer (score 1):

In his classic book on classical mechanics Whittaker calls these transformations Mathieu transformations. The term appears in Wikipedia.